# How to speed up numpy array iteration when constructing new image using array of coordinates from original image

Tags: performance, numpy, opencv, iteration

I need to construct new image based on coordinates representing pixels from original image. I got three arrays: one for new image, one for coordinates and one for original image. Arrays are shape of (480, 640, 3) except coordinate array which is (480, 640, 2). Here is my code.. it get's the job done, but it's very slow (fps ~1,8) for my purposes

```
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        y, x = coordinateMap.item((i, j, 0)), coordinateMap.item((i, j, 1))
        if y < 0 or y >= height or x < 0 or x >= width:
            value = (0,0,0)
        else:
            value = originalImage[y][x]
    newImage[i][j] = value
```

Is there way to get rid of that nested loop?

Comment: Can't guarantee it will do what you need without a bit more context, but I imagine that the remap() function might work, documented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4)

Comment: This is precisely what I needed! Thank you very much